# How can I understand like this "var vm = $scope.vm = {}" in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I read the angularJS api, I found the code like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var vm = $scope.vm = {name:'savo'};
    }
]);
```

This multiple assignments seems easy to understand.
But when I code like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       var vm = $scope.vm = {name:'savo'};
       vm.age = 18;
    }
]);
```

And the HTML like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <pre>{{vm}}</pre>
    <pre>{{vm.name}}</pre>
    <pre>{{vm.age}}</pre>
</div>
```

The results in the browser here:
[image]

Here is my question:
**The controller give the `vm` a attribute `age`, why the `vm` in the `$scope` has it too?**

When I use native JavaScript, this can not happen.
I can also change the two `vm` into different names,it won't change anything.

I'm new in angularJS,this just confusing me,Thanks for help!

By the way,why is angular use the name `vm`,does `vm` refer to some words abbreviation?

Comment: As for your last question, VM stands for view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here is my question: The controller give the vm a attribute age, why the vm in the $scope has it too?

Because variables `vm` and `$scope.vm` points to the same object. And since both are the same object, when you change one adding new property, the seconds changes too.

> When I use native JavaScript, this can not happen.

You are confused a little here. This is typical behaviour, due to the fact that all non-primitive (objects, functions, arrays, etc.) types in javascript are passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a little confused there in native JavaScript now I understand it!O(∩_∩)O